# php-Script changing string input encoding?

Tags: php, http, encoding, aes

I am working on a project where I need to pass an encrypted password through a php script. The password text is encrypted in aes. To see if the php script "read" the input string right, I echo out the input string. Unfortunately the encrypted text was different than what was inputed through the url.

Original test:

> Salted__1Y´NSÍMößlﬂ QÑ≈ˆ9%ÃíB5I

Encrypted on mac with command:

> openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -salt -in input.txt -out encryptedtext.txt

Encrypted with password: `test`

Command to decrypt: openssl enc -d -aes-256-cbc -in encryptedtext.txt

Decrypted Contents:`hi`

After I ran it through the script i got this:

> Salted__1YÂ´NSÃMÃ¶ÃŸlï¬‚ QÃ‘â‰ˆË†9%ÃƒÃ­B5I

I'm new at php and this stuff, so I'm not sure exactly what php does to the input strings. From what I can tell, it appears to change the encoding to something. If anyone knows why this is happening and how to prevent it, please let me know.

Comment: I don't know from where these alien characters came from, simplu use `md5+salt` or `sha1+salt`

Comment: @Mr.Alien That's not the same as *encryption* though. Assuming the OP actually needs *encryption* as opposed to simple password shadow storage.

Comment: @deceze I guess the question was edited later, because question was poorly asked so I was like what kind of encryption was going on here

Comment: a beauty of php is that it never mangles strings by worrying about stuff like encodings - it just treats them as binary and lets them be whatever they want to be.

Comment: @rambo What a beautiful description. "Lets them be whatever they want to be..." ^_^

Answer (score 1):

What you have there is binary gibberish anyway. It's not text. Any text it resolves to is just a coincidence of what characters it happens to represent in the chosen encoding.

...

Yes, that means the difference comes from the fact that the encoding used to interpret the binary gibberish is different. The original on the CLI may be interpreted as UTF-8, while the PHP output in the browser (?) is interpreted as Latin-1. Or some other combination.

If you're outputting to the browser, set the charset it should interpret the content with:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

Though what you have isn't text in some specific charset to begin with, so it doesn't make that much sense.

See [What Every Programmer Absolutely, Positively Needs To Know About Encodings And Character Sets To Work With Text](http://kunststube.net/encoding/) for background information.